# How can i show the image within the circle using qml?

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

Hi I'm new to blackberry. I want to **show the image within the circle using qul**.

Comment: Are you writing a pure Qt/QML application to run on BlackBerry 10, which is possible, or are you writing a Cascades application? If Cascades you should really use the blackberry-cascades tag instead of QML. Cascades does not implement all Qt objects and image handling is quite a bit different.

Comment: Yes I'm writing pure Qt/QML

Comment: Great, then @koopajah's answer should work for you.

Comment: I get the error **Type mismatch of value of the 'controls' default property. Expecting bb::cascades::Control and found Rectangle.**

Comment: There are two ways to tackle this depending on what you want to see outside the circle that contains the image. Do you want to see the underlying application elements, a transparent frame? Or do you want to have a frame with a circular opening in front of the image?

Comment: I want to show the image as round border.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to vignette an image is to overlay it with another image. In Cascades if you create a Container using either DockLayout or AbsoluteLayout you can position multiple ImageView objects on top of one another. The first object will be on the bottom, last on the top, by default. You simply create an image with a transparent viewport of the shape you want. You can scale the image at runtime but you should make it about the size of the largest frame you will need to preserve quality. I used Gimp to create a 786 x 78x pixel image with a white frame and a transparent circle in the middle and saved it to the assets directory as frame.png. I grabbed another image I had easily to hand and create a BlackBerry project with this QML code in an appropriate place:

```
Page {
        Container {
            layout: DockLayout {

            }
            ImageView {
                imageSource: "asset:///FusionMap.PNG"
                preferredHeight: 360
                preferredWidth: 360

            }
            ImageView {
                imageSource: "asset:///frame.png"
                preferredHeight: 360
                preferredWidth: 360

            }
        }
    }
```

This is the result:

[image]